# Openvpn：Could not resolve dns name

Tags: networking, dns, openvpn, dnsmasq

I set up an OpenVPN server at a remote cloud server, and config all routes to the dnsmasq that resides at the same OpenVPN server. I then downloaded all ca, and client keys in my local laptop. Once the laptop is connected to remote OpenVPN server, I would use DNS server at the OpenVPN server, and then all network connection would through the OpenVPN server.

Everything works ONLY when at my home. However， when I moved to another place (e.g., University office), all web sites could not be displayed. For exmaple, ping `www.google.com` on the console produces fails, while ping its IP address is OK.

```
hijiex@shijie-ThinkPad-T410:/other/dropxbox/Dropbox/project/IPRent/aliyun-us$ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
shijiex@shijie-ThinkPad-T410:/other/dropxbox/Dropbox/project/IPRent/aliyun-us$ ping 199.212.24.179 (google's IP)
PING 199.212.24.179 (199.212.24.179) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 199.212.24.179: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=294 ms

shijiex@shijie-ThinkPad-T410:/other/projectbase/dacapo/benchmarks/bms/batik/src/org/dacapo/harness$ ping 10.8.0.1
PING 10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=38.0 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=37.7 ms
```

The `client.conf` is

```
##############################################
# Sample client-side OpenVPN 2.0 config file #
# for connecting to multi-client server.     #
#                                            #
# This configuration can be used by multiple #
# clients, however each client should have   #
# its own cert and key files.                #
#                                            #
# On Windows, you might want to rename this  #
# file so it has a .ovpn extension           #
##############################################

# Specify that we are a client and that we
# will be pulling certain config file directives
# from the server.
client

# Use the same setting as you are using on
# the server.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel
# if you have more than one.  On XP SP2,
# you may need to disable the firewall
# for the TAP adapter.
;dev-node MyTap

# Are we connecting to a TCP or
# UDP server?  Use the same setting as
# on the server.
;proto tcp
proto udp

# The hostname/IP and port of the server.
# You can have multiple remote entries
# to load balance between the servers.
remote 47.90.206.48  1194
;remote my-server-2 1194

# Choose a random host from the remote
# list for load-balancing.  Otherwise
# try hosts in the order specified.
;remote-random

# Keep trying indefinitely to resolve the
# host name of the OpenVPN server.  Very useful
# on machines which are not permanently connected
# to the internet such as laptops.
resolv-retry infinite

# Most clients don't need to bind to
# a specific local port number.
nobind

# Downgrade privileges after initialization (non-Windows only)
;user nobody
;group nogroup

# Try to preserve some state across restarts.
persist-key
persist-tun

# If you are connecting through an
# HTTP proxy to reach the actual OpenVPN
# server, put the proxy server/IP and
# port number here.  See the man page
# if your proxy server requires
# authentication.
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]

# Wireless networks often produce a lot
# of duplicate packets.  Set this flag
# to silence duplicate packet warnings.
;mute-replay-warnings

# SSL/TLS parms.
# See the server config file for more
# description.  It's best to use
# a separate .crt/.key file pair
# for each client.  A single ca
# file can be used for all clients.
ca ca.crt
cert aliyun-us.crt
key aliyun-us.key

# Verify server certificate by checking
# that the certicate has the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  This is an
# important precaution to protect against
# a potential attack discussed here:
#  http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm
#
# To use this feature, you will need to generate
# your server certificates with the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  The build-key-server
# script in the easy-rsa folder will do this.
ns-cert-type server

# If a tls-auth key is used on the server
# then every client must also have the key.
;tls-auth ta.key 1

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# If the cipher option is used on the server
# then you must also specify it here.
;cipher x

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# Don't enable this unless it is also
# enabled in the server config file.
comp-lzo

# Set log file verbosity.
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages
;mute 20
```

I checked the server and everything is still there. When I moved the laptop back to the home, it works again.

The　client's console:

```
Mon Apr  3 14:41:00 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Mon Apr  3 14:41:00 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Mon Apr  3 14:41:00 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Mon Apr  3 14:41:00 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Mon Apr  3 14:41:00 2017 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Mon Apr  3 14:41:00 2017 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]47.90.206.48:1194
Mon Apr  3 14:41:03 2017 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5'
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 ROUTE_GATEWAY 131.202.102.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlan0 HWADDR=00:23:14:40:24:84
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.6 peer 10.8.0.5
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 /sbin/ip route add 47.90.206.48/32 via 131.202.102.1
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.5
Mon Apr  3 14:41:05 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

**Updated  VPN server.conf:**

```
# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
;local a.b.c.d

# Which TCP/UDP port should OpenVPN listen on?
# If you want to run multiple OpenVPN instances
# on the same machine, use a different port
# number for each one.  You will need to
# open up this port on your firewall.
port 1194

# TCP or UDP server?
;proto tcp
proto udp

# "dev tun" will create a routed IP tunnel,
# "dev tap" will create an ethernet tunnel.
# Use "dev tap0" if you are ethernet bridging
# and have precreated a tap0 virtual interface
# and bridged it with your ethernet interface.
# If you want to control access policies
# over the VPN, you must create firewall
# rules for the the TUN/TAP interface.
# On non-Windows systems, you can give
# an explicit unit number, such as tun0.
# On Windows, use "dev-node" for this.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel if you
# have more than one.  On XP SP2 or higher,
# you may need to selectively disable the
# Windows firewall for the TAP adapter.
# Non-Windows systems usually don't need this.
;dev-node MyTap

# SSL/TLS root certificate (ca), certificate
# (cert), and private key (key).  Each client
# and the server must have their own cert and
# key file.  The server and all clients will
# use the same ca file.
#
# See the "easy-rsa" directory for a series
# of scripts for generating RSA certificates
# and private keys.  Remember to use
# a unique Common Name for the server
# and each of the client certificates.
#
# Any X509 key management system can be used.
# OpenVPN can also use a PKCS #12 formatted key file
# (see "pkcs12" directive in man page).
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret

# Diffie hellman parameters.
# Generate your own with:
#   openssl dhparam -out dh2048.pem 2048
dh dh2048.pem

# Network topology
# Should be subnet (addressing via IP)
# unless Windows clients v2.0.9 and lower have to
# be supported (then net30, i.e. a /30 per client)
# Defaults to net30 (not recommended)
;topology subnet

# Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
# for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
# The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself,
# the rest will be made available to clients.
# Each client will be able to reach the server
# on 10.8.0.1. Comment this line out if you are
# ethernet bridging. See the man page for more info.
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

# Maintain a record of client <-> virtual IP address
# associations in this file.  If OpenVPN goes down or
# is restarted, reconnecting clients can be assigned
# the same virtual IP address from the pool that was
# previously assigned.
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging.
# You must first use your OS's bridging capability
# to bridge the TAP interface with the ethernet
# NIC interface.  Then you must manually set the
# IP/netmask on the bridge interface, here we
# assume 10.8.0.4/255.255.255.0.  Finally we
# must set aside an IP range in this subnet
# (start=10.8.0.50 end=10.8.0.100) to allocate
# to connecting clients.  Leave this line commented
# out unless you are ethernet bridging.
;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging
# using a DHCP-proxy, where clients talk
# to the OpenVPN server-side DHCP server
# to receive their IP address allocation
# and DNS server addresses.  You must first use
# your OS's bridging capability to bridge the TAP
# interface with the ethernet NIC interface.
# Note: this mode only works on clients (such as
# Windows), where the client-side TAP adapter is
# bound to a DHCP client.
;server-bridge

# Push routes to the client to allow it
# to reach other private subnets behind
# the server.  Remember that these
# private subnets will also need
# to know to route the OpenVPN client
# address pool (10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0)
# back to the OpenVPN server.
;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"

# To assign specific IP addresses to specific
# clients or if a connecting client has a private
# subnet behind it that should also have VPN access,
# use the subdirectory "ccd" for client-specific
# configuration files (see man page for more info).

# EXAMPLE: Suppose the client
# having the certificate common name "Thelonious"
# also has a small subnet behind his connecting
# machine, such as 192.168.40.128/255.255.255.248.
# First, uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# Then create a file ccd/Thelonious with this line:
#   iroute 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# This will allow Thelonious' private subnet to
# access the VPN.  This example will only work
# if you are routing, not bridging, i.e. you are
# using "dev tun" and "server" directives.

# EXAMPLE: Suppose you want to give
# Thelonious a fixed VPN IP address of 10.9.0.1.
# First uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
# Then add this line to ccd/Thelonious:
#   ifconfig-push 10.9.0.1 10.9.0.2

# Suppose that you want to enable different
# firewall access policies for different groups
# of clients.  There are two methods:
# (1) Run multiple OpenVPN daemons, one for each
#     group, and firewall the TUN/TAP interface
#     for each group/daemon appropriately.
# (2) (Advanced) Create a script to dynamically
#     modify the firewall in response to access
#     from different clients.  See man
#     page for more info on learn-address script.
;learn-address ./script

# If enabled, this directive will configure
# all clients to redirect their default
# network gateway through the VPN, causing
# all IP traffic such as web browsing and
# and DNS lookups to go through the VPN
# (The OpenVPN server machine may need to NAT
# or bridge the TUN/TAP interface to the internet
# in order for this to work properly).
;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

# Certain Windows-specific network settings
# can be pushed to clients, such as DNS
# or WINS server addresses.  CAVEAT:
# http://openvpn.net/faq.html#dhcpcaveats
# The addresses below refer to the public
# DNS servers provided by opendns.com.
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

# Uncomment this directive to allow different
# clients to be able to "see" each other.
# By default, clients will only see the server.
# To force clients to only see the server, you
# will also need to appropriately firewall the
# server's TUN/TAP interface.
;client-to-client

# Uncomment this directive if multiple clients
# might connect with the same certificate/key
# files or common names.  This is recommended
# only for testing purposes.  For production use,
# each client should have its own certificate/key
# pair.
#
# IF YOU HAVE NOT GENERATED INDIVIDUAL
# CERTIFICATE/KEY PAIRS FOR EACH CLIENT,
# EACH HAVING ITS OWN UNIQUE "COMMON NAME",
# UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OUT.
;duplicate-cn

# The keepalive directive causes ping-like
# messages to be sent back and forth over
# the link so that each side knows when
# the other side has gone down.
# Ping every 10 seconds, assume that remote
# peer is down if no ping received during
# a 120 second time period.
keepalive 10 120

# For extra security beyond that provided
# by SSL/TLS, create an "HMAC firewall"
# to help block DoS attacks and UDP port flooding.
#
# Generate with:
#   openvpn --genkey --secret ta.key
#
# The server and each client must have
# a copy of this key.
# The second parameter should be '0'
# on the server and '1' on the clients.
;tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# This config item must be copied to
# the client config file as well.
;cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)
;cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
;cipher DES-EDE3-CBC  # Triple-DES

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# If you enable it here, you must also
# enable it in the client config file.
comp-lzo

# The maximum number of concurrently connected
# clients we want to allow.
;max-clients 100

# It's a good idea to reduce the OpenVPN
# daemon's privileges after initialization.
#
# You can uncomment this out on
# non-Windows systems.
;user nobody

;group nogroup

# The persist options will try to avoid
# accessing certain resources on restart
# that may no longer be accessible because
# of the privilege downgrade.
persist-key
persist-tun

# Output a short status file showing
# current connections, truncated
# and rewritten every minute.
status openvpn-status.log

# By default, log messages will go to the syslog (or
# on Windows, if running as a service, they will go to
# the "\Program Files\OpenVPN\log" directory).
# Use log or log-append to override this default.
# "log" will truncate the log file on OpenVPN startup,
# while "log-append" will append to it.  Use one
# or the other (but not both).
;log         openvpn.log
;log-append  openvpn.log

# Set the appropriate level of log
# file verbosity.
#
# 0 is silent, except for fatal errors
# 4 is reasonable for general usage
# 5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems
# 9 is extremely verbose
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages.  At most 20
# sequential messages of the same message
# category will be output to the log.
;mute 20
;push "redirect-gateway def1" push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
;push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

/etc/rc.local:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

service dnsmasq restart
exit 0
```

and /etc/sysctl.conf:  `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

I also configured the IP forward rules at the server side.

Thanks

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean, specifically?

Comment: @OrganicMarble All web sites could not be displayed. Try to ping "www.google.com", but reports unknown host finally..

Comment: Did you add the push lines in your server.conf? push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

Comment: Are you pushing DNS to the client with a directive like `push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"`? Do you have a directive like `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"`?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes, I push DNS to clients, and let all traffics go through the VPN. I post my server.conf, which has `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"`. In my home, I can connect to the server and everything is OK. But when my laptop is moved to the university office, all host names can not be resolved.

Comment: @ubfan1 see my previous ans for @organic. The server.conf does not have this configuration (See the last two lines at `server.conf`). What's the difference between them? The `server.conf` is copied from templates with limited my modifications.

Comment: It's confusing to read your server.conf because you have the redirect gateway commented out (twice) and then later you added it back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uncomment the lines (which already exist in your server.conf file at line 111) by removing the semi colon (;):

```
# DNS servers provided by opendns.com.
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
```

in your server.conf file.

At home, your DNS was probably supplied by your router.

---

Note, you should have select a 10.x.x.x network distinct from your remote site.  Things get all mixed up otherwise.
1) Your updated server.conf file still has  the semicolons -- remove them.
2)When given a template, use it, don't scramble the lines around unless you know that will not cause problems.  Uncomment the dhcp=-redirect rather than just adding it at the end -- I don't know if it can follow the dhpc-option lines or not, but change the minimum to eliminate possible problem investigations.
3) Remove the ; on the tls-auth line
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
4) Add key-direction 0 just after the tls-auth line.
5) For Ubuntu clients, uncomment the user and group. both server.conf and client.conf If you are trying to set up a Windows client, you are asking in the wrong site.

Comment: Do you mean to append the two provided  configurations to the server.conf?  Can you help explain why it is OK in my home, while unknown host error when moving to the office? Thanks

Comment: I agree that you need to do this.  This way your client will use the OpenDNS servers.

Comment: Thanks both. Uncomment two `push dhcp-options`, see updated `server.conf`. Then restart openvpn and dnsmq in order. But the issue still there: my browser could not show any pages when in office.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/resolv.conf` file defines where your computer should look to resolve hostnames into IP addresses.  The basic problem is that `/etc/resolv.conf` doesn't get updated when you run `openvpn` by default.

Here's what you need to do to fix the problem.

1.) Append the following onto your `server.conf` file on your OpenVPN server machine (typically located at `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`) to have the server to the client where to look to convert hostnames to IP addresses.

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN mylocaldomain.lan"
```

2.) Install `resolvconf` on your client machine and link the standard `resolv.conf` to `resolvconf`'s version with the following commands to have a function capable of modifying `resolv.conf`

```
sudo apt install resolvconf
sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.orig
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

3.) Append the following to the bottom of your `client.ovpn` file to run `resolvconf` whenver the OpenVPN server is connected to or disconnected from.

```
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

4.) Whenever you run `openvpn` you'll have to do so with the `-script-security 2` flag to allow `openvpn` to run `resolvconf`.  Here is an example call

```
sudo openvpn --script-security 2 --config /path/to/client.ovpn
```

You can read a more detailed version of the above instructions with some example code of my (working) OpenVPN server here: https://steamforge.net/wiki/index.php/How_to_configure_OpenVPN_to_resolve_local_DNS_%26_hostnames